# Flask-SQLAlchemy self-referential many-to-many association object

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm building a user-friendships mechanism using flask sqlalchemy. I want a 'boss-employee relationship' object so it could have some other attributes such as date, nicknames and such, and maintain a work tree of the employees.

I realized the best way to achieve this is using an association object connected to a self-referential many to many relationship of the user model. The models seem to work, but I can't seem to actually add data using them.

Can anyone direct me to fixing this? Thank you!

This is what I run in the interpreter to add a relationship, and it crashes every time:

```
from questionary import create_app
app = create_app()
app.app_context().push()
from questionary import db
db.create_all()
from questionary.models import *
s, m = User.query.all()[0], User.query.all()[-1]
r = RelationshipObject(slave=s, master=m)
db.session.add(r)
db.session.commit()
```

With the error:

```
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\project\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1247                     self.dialect.do_execute(
-> 1248                         cursor, statement, parameters, context
   1249                     )

d:\project\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py in do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    589     def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 590         cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    591 

ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'User'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

(...long recursion error traceback here...)

d:\project\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py in do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    588
    589     def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 590         cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    591
    592     def do_execute_no_params(self, cursor, statement, context=None):

<class 'str'>: (<class 'RecursionError'>, RecursionError('maximum recursion depth exceeded in __instancecheck__'))
```

These are my models, and I'm using a package structured flask model, and running from the tree base.

```
class RelationshipObject(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    slave = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
        'user.id'), primary_key=True)
    master = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
        'user.id'), primary_key=True)
    relationship_time = db.Column(
        db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=dt.utcnow)

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    slaves = db.relationship('RelationshipObject', backref='slaves',
                             primaryjoin=(id == RelationshipObject.slave))
    masters = db.relationship('RelationshipObject', backref='masters',
                              primaryjoin=(id == RelationshipObject.master))
```

Comment: My best guess is that the User table, as created in the database, doesn't match your model. That's usually what that ProgrammingError message means.